# Search for pattern and add sequential number to end of each line where pattern occurs

Tags: vim, vi

I want to search for a pattern and add sequential number to end of line.
For example, I have following text file.

```
Male
John  #
Tom   #
Jack  #

Female
Mary  #
Jenny #
```

I want to search pattern "#" and add sequential number end of line.

```
Male
John  #0
Tom   #1
Jack  #2

Female
Mary  #3
Jenny #4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could substitute with ascending numbers, as explained in this [tip from the Vim Wiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Making_a_list_of_numbers):

```
:let i=1 | g/#$/s//\='#'.i/ | let i=i+1
```